# Autodelete person from group in Directory Assistance

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

We have a server with DA (associated address book) configured.
The DA is used mainly to created mail groups (it does not have any person documents).

Whenever a person is removed from main address book, the person is also automatically removed from all the groups that he/she was listed in (in the main address book). However, a user doesn't get removed from any of the groups that he/she is listed in the Associates Address Book.

Is this misconfiguration? or it just does not work in a way we expect.
Do we have to do some extra work (like create a schedule agent in DA) that verify groups and perform clean up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The administration process takes care for renames and deletions. But it has to KNOW that it is responsible for your secondary address book.

Modify the ACL of that secondary names.nsf and set its server as „Administration Server“ and select „Modify all Names Fields“ from the options. Now the server knows, that on the next run of an admin process it has to take care of that addressbook as well.